# Print users' data inside a template in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to print users' information such as email, first name, username in a template that should work as "My Profile Page".

For some reason, the only thing I'm able to print is the username of the logged-in user with `{{request.user.username}}` and the id (both `{{request.user.id}}` and `{{user.id}}` work)

Users are registered using the *UserCreationForm*

If I try to print the email with `{{request.user.email}}` or `{{user.email}}` nothing is shown.

My settings.py is the default one

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: what happens if you try to print user's id? like {{request.user.id}} or {{user.id}} ?

Comment: @SergeyPugach both correctly print the ID of the logged in user

Comment: My assumption that your user `email` field is not required and it's None that is why it's not printed.
You can change it either via admin or via Django shell `./manage.py shell` find your user `user = User.objects.get(id=your_id)` then `user.email = 'mycoolemail@email.com' `and `user.save()` and check.

Comment: @SergeyPugach I'm pretty dumb... Just found out the user I was using had no email added to its profile...

Comment: Posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption that your user email field is not required and it's None that is why it's not printed. You can change it either via admin or via Django shell `./manage.py shell` find your user `user = User.objects.get(id=your_id)` then `user.email = 'mycoolemail@email.com'` and `user.save()` and check